# ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, airflow-2.x

i have freshly installed on ec2 instance on ubuntu, the installation was successfull but after that when i try to run "airflow standalone" to run airflow, it won't start.

Below is the error i get, do i need to install anything else also before running "airflow standlone" command.
My ultimate goal is to deploy python code for data transformation in my data-pipeline.

please help ?

webserver | [2022-11-01 10:36:51,919] {webserver_command.py:217} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
webserver | [2022-11-01 10:36:51,920] {webserver_command.py:218} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
scheduler | [2022-11-01 10:39:38,254] {scheduler_job.py:1381} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs